# Javascript comparing the keys of a json file

Tags: javascript, json, file, dictionary

I have json files for application translations, I would like to make sure to compare the two files, so as to know if there are any differences.

Such as:

- the key name are different
- the name of a key exists in one file and not in another

So I have to compare the name of the keys and not the text they contain.

Eventually I would like to know the different key name (key path).

Can you give me some advice on how I could do it?

Comment: You should post  Json files if you hope to find some help. They way to compare depends on the content and the size of files.  We need to know how complicated are properties and how deep nested for example .

Comment: Here is an example of what I'm trying: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-bash-hmgqde?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I thought I would take all the names of the keys and then compare the two files, using the keys.